# Additional parameters in output callback

Tags: angular

Is there way to pass more parameters in parent component to `@Output` callback from child component? I have a dynamic list of child components, where user can do some action. I want to know in which component he performed the action.

```html
<div *ngFor="let order of orders; let i=index">
  <h1>{{order.title}}</h1>
  <child-component (onAction)="childComponentAction($event, i)"></child-component>
</div>
```

```js
childComponentAction(actionResult: string, ind: number){
  //some code here
}
```

Comment: You don't need the extra param, the parent already knows which one it is with i. Output is in the child component, it will just emit the event.

Comment: You can only pass a single value, but you can pass an object value that has multiple properties.